# Мультиязычность на сайте с помощью nginx

Tags: nginx, cookie, mod-rewrite, multilanguage

Нужна помощь. Есть сайт site.com. Он мультиязычный. Т.е. исходим из того, что языков неограничено.
Сайт сам статический (набор HTML-ок).

Структура языков такая

https://site.com/* - EN

https://site.com/ru/ - RU

https://site.com/kr/ - Корейский
и т.д.

например

https://site.com/page1/

https://site.com/ru/page1/

https://site.com/kr/page1/

Я хочу реализовать смену языка на сайте при первом заходе. Т.е. с помощью nginx получать язык браузера пользователя, затем сравнивать с языком сайта (для этого достаточно смотреть УРЛ) и если язык отличается, то искать папку на nginx (например для CDN русской версии - /ru/page1/index.html) и если она есть - перебрасывать на нужный язык. При это вне зависимости, совпали языки или нет, нужно создать cookie с именем moved, значением 1 сроком на 365 дней для корня сайта. Эту куку мы будем проверять, перемещали ли мы человека уже или нет. Т.е. если кука есть и равна 1, то ничего не делаем.

Как это реализовать правильно?

Comment: вопрос чересчур глобален. задавайте, пожалуйста, более конкретные вопросы.

Comment: Ну примерно так и реализовать как вы описали.

Comment: Хотя получение языка по браузеру на nginx уже не очень тривиальная задача